# What's the best way to temporarily persist results of a long running SP?

Tags: t-sql, time

I have a TSQL stored procedure that can run for a few minutes and return a few million records, I need to display that data in an ASP.NET Grid (Infragistics WebDataGrid to be precise). Obviously I don't want return all data at once and need to setup some kind of paging options - every time user selects another page - another portion of data is loaded from the DB. But I can't run the SP every time new page is requested - it would take too much time.

What would be the best way to persist data from the SP, so when user selects a new page - new data portion would be loaded by a simple SELECT... WHERE from that temp data storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few options

One: 
If the user only pages forward then you could just hold the connection open and use a DataReader.  Just .Read() as needed.

Two: 
Create a #temp table using the userID as part of the name to store the results.  I don't like this as if user aborts sometimes tables are left over.  About 1/2 second hit to create and drop the #temp.  Store the entire results or just the PK and create the page detail on demand.

Three:
Use a DataReader to read the the PK into a List<>.  It is faster than you would guess.  That List is only going to IIS (not to the browser).  List can be referenced by ordinal [] and preserves the sort.  Get the detail for a page as required.  The problem here is where PK in (3,9,2,6)  will not return them in that order.  I use TVP to pass the order, PK so the page is sorted by order.   I do exactly this and get pages loads for objects with 20 properties 40 rows at a time and it takes less than 1/2 second.   Do one query per table (NOT one per row) then assemble assign properties in .NET.  Use DataReader (not DataTable).  And you can even run the reader on a backgroundworker and pass back the first page of PKs using progresschanged.

Comment: For the (3) to work the result of the SP, actual data in the backend has to be stored somewhere? Where would I store it? Thanks!

Comment: Use a DataReader to read the PK into a List<>;  Then you pass one page at a time of the PK list to the SP via the TVP (Table Value Parameter).  I will post some code.

Comment: This is the article I used.  http://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2009/07/29/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters-and-c-custom-iterators-a-match-made-in-heaven/  Where my List<> PK may have 600,000 rows I only pass 40 at a time via the TVP to get the details and I pass both the order and PK to the TVP so I can get the result of 40 in the proper order.

Comment: Excellent article, thanks for the link! I will investigate this approach. Even though some of users still use SQL Server 2005, I may find an efficient way instead of TVP to pass list of PKs to SP. And I believe using just PKs known in advance instead of original parameters SP will run faster. But if not - my original issue remains, I need resultset from that long-running SP to be temporary stored somewhere (full set of data, not just PKs) so that consecutive calls can retrieve data (e.g. using PKs) from it quickly.

Comment: Why do you need to store the full data?  If you need to store the full data then Two: #Temp tables.  If non key data changes between when they view the detail and when they ran the SP you need them to see a snap shot of the data at the time the SP was run rather than current data?

Comment: Full data is needed because SP is expensive to run for every user request. So the scenario is this:

1. At initial user request (e.g. user clicks button "Get Data") SP runs and brings full initial dataset into a temp storage
2. At this time user should be able to further filter data, search for specific data within the result set, group data, sort data, jump to any page within the data and these are ad-hoc request, done on the fly and need to execute very fast, so passing these requests to the SP is out of the question, the requests have to be done to the data already retrieved in Step 1.

Comment: Ordinary #temp tables won't work because requests to DB are made from ASP.NET code and connection to the server is created at the beginning of every request and destroyed when request is complete.

Comment: ASP.NET has a Session.  You can create the #temp and hold it for the Session.  You REALLY need to take snap shot of over a 1 million records and hold the key an non-key elements?  Please explain the business need.

Comment: Going back to the original idea, I think this is a way to go - get full list of PKs and then request 1 page at a time by passing 40-50 PKs at a time to the backend query. My only 2 concerns remain: ad-hock filtering and sorting - e.g. User looks at the data, pages thru it and at some point selects a column filter (excel-like, many grid controls offer this UI) or clicks a column to sort by it. Any idea how to tie this to the above method where all PKs are already retreived in advance?

Comment: Store the PK for the current search and sort.  If the user has a new search or sort then start over.   If you want to get real fancy you could sort on prior search results but most likley it is faster to just submitt the query with new sort.

Comment: This approach seem to be working pretty good, but my current problem - as you mentioned it - sorting is not preserved. I cannot use TVPs since some of the clients are on SQL Server 2005; so currently I am passing list of IDs as comma-separated string. Any idea how to preserve original sorting of IDs in that scenario? Thanks!

Comment: Then need to create at #temp and insert the PK, sort in that table.  The you join #temp to data table for the query and sort on #temp.order.   I did this before I discovered TVP.

Comment: Actually (and this was very stupid of me) I realized what was happening. I am already creating #temp table based on that comma separated list, but I stupidly was indexing that table based on IDs - and of course the index sorted the table by IDs. But is there any other way to speed it up (I wanted that index to avoid things like table scan when joining to data table) while preserving original sort?

Comment: Are having performance issues?   The join is to the PK which is indexed.   I am using this going against tables with million of rows getting 100 at a time in less than 1 second.  It seems to help the query optimizer to declare the PK on the #temp.

Comment: Yup. You're right no need to index that temp table; getting 400-500 ms for retrieving full data list (20-30 columns of data) even if the ID list is not indexed. Thanks again for the great idea!

Comment: You DO want a PK on the index table.  It will help the query optimizer.   And it won't hurt.   It tell the query optimizer that if is finds a hit it can stop looking as there cannot be more than 1 match.

Comment: It's a temp table with 100 integers only if I index it - the speed difference is 2-3 milliseconds (even though it joins the data with hundreds of thousands of rows), and I have to do extra work to sort the result. On the other hand if I don't PK it - original order of IDs is preserved.

Comment: In absence of a sort there is not guaranteed sort order.  Another query may not return the rows in that same order.    In a simple join with no other where conditions you will typically get the rows in the order of the small table but may not.   Even a query on a single table with a clustered PK is not guaranteed to return the rows in the order of the clustered PK without a sort.

Answer (score 1):

Have you look at [Server Side Paging](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/server-side-paging-using-sql-server-2005) (article is 2005, but will work with 2008 and CTEs). Also - just wondering, is there any reason you are returning that many rows? I can't see a very good use of a human paging through a million records even if the page size was 1000.

Comment: This might be a silly question, but, wouldn't server side paging still retrieve all the records before filtering and ordering? Or am I just saying something stupid?

Comment: I asked it cause I was reading this article about OFFSET at sqlservercentral http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlservernotesfromthefield/2011/08/09/server-side-paging-with-new-offset-feature-in-sql-server-denali/

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, I was going to use approach similar to this, but for it to work I need the result of the SP to be in some kind of Temp table for all those SELECTs... made from Web Page to work. I need that temp storage to be persistent enough so the data will stay there between different paging calls (possibly between new connections to SQL server made from the ASP.NET code) but volatile enough so if user simple closes the page - the data won't stay there forever but gets dropped graciously.

Comment: As to why so many records needed in advance - most likely user won't page through initial data set directly, but will be additionally grouping and filtering the data, but this is needed to be done on the fly and very fast, hence filtering/grouping should be done on the resultset, returned by the SP, similar to paging I cannot call the SP every time grouping/filtering is requested.